# Slope of a channel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, water, flow

I have a trapezoidal channel like this:

[image: Trapezoidal channel]

> The question is to get the slope of the channel such that we have a [Chézy coefficient](http://www.google.com/search?q=chezy+coefficient) of 64 $m^{1/2}/s$.
>
> Given: $B= 76\: \mathrm{m}$, $y = 10\: \mathrm{m}$, $\tan(\gamma) = 5/12$ where $\gamma$ is the angle between the horizontal line and the oblique line. $q= 1200\: \mathrm{m^3/s}$.

Here is how I solved it:

we know that $$ v = C \sqrt{ R\space i}$$

so $$ i = \frac{v^2}{C^2 \times R}$$
$$v = \frac{q}{S} = \frac {1200}{ y \times(B + \frac{y}{\tan(\gamma)})} = 1.2\: \mathrm{m/s}$$

$$R = \frac{1000}{76 + \frac {20}{5/12}}=7.8\: \mathrm{m}$$
and then we have:

$$i = \frac{1.2^2}{64^2 \times 7.8} = 4.5 \times 10^{-5}$$

## Question:

Is this an expected value of a slope? shouldn't this be something like: $4.5$ or $45$?

Comment: Math seems correct to me

Comment: @Michiel I verified that everything related to math is correct before I ask here.

Comment: Hi user689. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: @Qmechanic thanks I will be more careful about such questions next time.

Comment: Note that the slope is in $m/m$ so a slope of 45 is an almost 90 degree drop and 4.5 is also already 77 degrees. That said, I think a slope of only $10^{-5}$ seems a bit small

Comment: @Michiel can you explain how a slope of 45 is 90 degrees? How do you transform from m/m to degrees?

Comment: $m/m$ refers to how many meters in height the channel changes for a given meter of horizontal distance. That means that $45 m/m$ is a change of 45 meters in height for 1 $m$ of distance which is obviously close to 90 degrees. To be exact it is: $Arctan(45/1)=88.7$ degrees

Comment: Because there is a bounty I can't vote to close the question even though it doesn't conform to our homework policy @Qmechanic linked to above. There are no conceptual questions asked and it appears to just be looking for somebody to check the work of the questioner.

Comment: @tpg2114 not to mention the question is basically algebra and explicitly violates the "check my work" sorts of questions that are explicitly off-topic here.  This question offers no value to anyone in the community and sets a bad example.

Comment: @tpg2114 I'm not looking for somebody to check my question, I've already stated that I checked the math calculation and I'm sure it is right. My question was: `is this an expected value of a slope and why`

Comment: @user689 That is still not a physics or conceptual question. A slope can be any real number from 0 to $\pi/2$ and you're within those bounds. So there isn't anything about it that's on topic if all you want is to know if your number is reasonable.

Comment: @tpg2114 too bad that I lost 50 points for something silly like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with this result. First of all, the math is correct, though

\begin{equation}
R = \frac{1000}{76 + \frac{20}{5/12}} \approx 8.06 \ m
\end{equation}

but the change to your result is negligible. Second, it is consistent with the [Manning Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manning_formula)

\begin{equation}
v = \frac{1}{n} R^{2/3} S^{1/2}
\end{equation}

for your calculated velocity, slope, and hydraulic radius. Solving for the Manning coefficient gives $n \approx 0.022$, well in the [ballpark of most materials](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/mannings-roughness-d_799.html), which is between 0.01 and 0.1 (in fact, it seems to be closest to corrugated metal).

The reason your slope is so small is because the mean velocity is very small relative to the desired Chézy coefficient, though this is not something one could point out from a first-glance examination of the problem.